# Solution of Congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

So I understand that when you have $a \equiv b \bmod m$ that means that $(a-b)=qm$ for some integer $q$

But I find the topic really confusing. Below is a question I had recently, and I would appreciate some advice on how to answer it, so far all that I have read, been taught, has been quite confusing:

Find a solution of the congruence;
$1990x \equiv 15 \bmod 2015$

Comment: Are you sure you need to find *a solution*, and not *all solutions*? In any case, this is called a linear congruence, just Google it, there are countless resources about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is a solution if and only if :

$$1990x-15 \text{ is divisible by } 2015 $$

if and only if we can find $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that :

$$1990x+2015m=15 $$

if and only if we can find $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that :

$$398x+403m=3 $$

Now justify that $398$ and $403$ are prime to each other by computing the Euclidean algorithm and find a Bezout identity (using the same Euclidean algorithm) :

$$398u+403v=1 $$

Deduce from this an $x$ that will do the job.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I haven't had it broken down like that before, Thank you! @Clément